# (JavaScript) How can I reuse the content inside the event click listener?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
document.querySelector(".tables").querySelectorAll("table").forEach((ele)=>{
  ele.querySelector(".showProfile")?.addEventListener("click",async (e) =>{
     //## code ##
  })
})
```

Even if I don't click on this part(## code ##), I want to use it again.

I wonder if there is any way.

Simply put, when clicked, the logic inside is to open a window containing the member's information.
However, currently, when a window is opened and the contents are modified, the window is turned off with redirection.
So I want to open the window again, not just a simple redirect when I modify it.

Comment: I'm confused by your question but `window.open(\`${url}\`, "_blank");` can be used if you are trying to open a new tab in JavaScript. Or you could save a redirect_url in SessionStorage if you want to persist state between pages.

Answer (score 4):

Can't u just wrap it into a function and then reuse it?

```
document.querySelector(".tables").querySelectorAll("table").forEach((ele)=>{
  ele.querySelector(".showProfile")?.addEventListener("click",async (e) =>{
     a(e);
  })
})

function a(e) {
  ## code ##
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick reply.
But ultimately it's not what I want.

Simply put, when clicked, the logic inside is to open a window containing the member's information.
However, currently, when a window is opened and the contents are modified, the window is turned off with redirection.
So I want to open the window again, not just a simple redirect when I modify it.